# Create java jar file that creates and connects to Android Sqlite3 database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am creating a java jar file that will be used to connect to different databases so this library can be used in many apps and support different databases. i.e. Sqlite3, MySQL, Oracle, etc.

Currently I want to support Android first and want my jar file to connect to Android's builtin Sqlite3 database.

The customer will use are jar file and call the functions in it to create, update, and query the database. So they won't have to use any or Androids API.

However, I am confused about a few things:

```
1) Can a java jar file create and connect to Android Sqlite3 database without importing the android.database.sqlite.* API. Just using Java's standard API?
2) As all apps are created and ran in their own sandbox on Android, will the database be created and saved to the apps sandbox for security reasons?
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Can you try for greenDAO? I guess, it'll help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you want to create and connect to the built-in android sqlite database you must import `android.database.sqlite.*`

About the other section of the question, i'm not sure if it's depends on the first one or not but if you use the android api to create it, sure it will be in the application private folder

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In order to connect to Android's sqlite you need the JDBC and google hasn't developed the JDBC for connecting to sqlite running on Android.

Answer (score 1):

> Can a java jar file create and connect to Android Sqlite3 database without importing the android.database.sqlite.* API. Just using Java's standard API?

sqlite databases are just files. You can read and write files with regular Java APIs.

Though for database use it's better to use the sqlite3 C library for reading and writing the files. Android provides one Java wrapper for it; there are a number of other wrappers as well, including JDBC ones.

> As all apps are created and ran in their own sandbox on Android, will the database be created and saved to the apps sandbox for security reasons?

By default the Android database wrapper puts database files in the app's private data directory. It's not accessible to other apps without shared user id or root.